# scipy.optimize with SLSQP. 'Singular matrix E in LSQ subproblem' for certain constraints

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have the following function that I want to maximize:

```
def func(x):
    cycles = [8,5,4,10,12,30,15]
    temp = [(7*3*3600*_[1])/(_[0]) for _ in zip(cycles,x)]
    return -1*min(temp)
```

with the constraint that the sum of the input array is less than some (given) value:

```
def constraint(x,maxValue):
    return maxValue - sum(x)
```

Plugging it into scipy's minimize with the "maxValue" set to 33.25:

```
x0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
f = lambda x: constraint(x,maxValue=33.25)
cons = {'type':'ineq','fun':f}
resp =  minimize(func,x0,constraints=cons)
```

which yields the result

```
fun: -29924.428434921883
jac: array([ 0., -1.34570312,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
message: 'Singular matrix E in LSQ subproblem'
nfev: 1062
nit: 77
njev: 77
status: 5
success: False
x: array([ 3.16672131,1.97912886,1.583527,3.95825773,4.74999599,11.87498921,5.9373869 ])
```

However, if I try it with "maxValue" set to values around 33.25, like 33.24 or 33.26, it completes successfully.

output with maxValue = 33.26

```
fun: -29933.28915480171
jac: array([    0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0., -5040.])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 655
nit: 50
njev: 50
status: 0
success: True
x: array([ 3.16766655,1.97971518,1.58403593,3.95950332,4.7514066,11.87851562,5.93914467])
```

My current work-around for status code 5 is to check values around it (+/- 0.1 at the moment) to see if it succeeds, but I would like a better idea on *why* its failing, but cant find any explanation of matrix E.

Comment: `func` looks incomplete or `cycles` should be renamed to `cycleTimes`. When i do that, i obtain results, but those are different. This is something to analyze, but i won't as i don't like to guess about non-working code. This might be due to different versions, where probably numerical-differentiation changed somehow, which is emphasized by bad-scaling (the magnitude of `5*7*3*3600` is not nice for the solver) or i'm interpreting that code wrongly. So scaling would be a good idea.The **core problem** however: the optimizer assumes *twice-differentiability* and `min(temp)` is not differentiable

Comment: You need to *linearize* `min(temp)`, which is for example possible by reformulation, which results in many new constraints. But this will also hurt the solver. A better approach (disclaimer: i did not check convexity; and something more restrictive might render the following non-doable) for the example, imho, would be using cvxpy, which 1) does this linearization automatically and 2) brings solvers more suited for this linearization.

Comment: Thank you for the response sascha; I'll look into cvxpy. 
You are right about the cycles/cycleTimes discrepancy; I was modifying some variable names while pasting and missed that one; which should now be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack with [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) (comments above explain why the original approach is failing and why cvxpy is a *good* candidate):

```
import numpy as np 
import cvxpy as cp

# CONSTANTS
# ---------

maxValue = 33.26
cycles = np.array([8,5,4,10,12,30,15])
factor = 7*3*3600

# OPT PROBLEM
# -----------

x = cp.Variable(7)
constraints = [cp.sum(x) <= maxValue]
obj = cp.Minimize(-cp.min((x * factor) / cycles))
problem = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
problem.solve(verbose=True, solver=cp.ECOS)

print(problem.value)
print(x.value)
```

Output:

```
ECOS 2.0.7 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
0  -2.993e+04  -2.994e+04  +1e+00  1e-05  3e-04  1e+00  3e-01    ---    ---    1  1  - |  -  - 
1  -2.993e+04  -2.993e+04  +1e-02  1e-07  4e-06  1e-02  3e-03  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0
2  -2.993e+04  -2.993e+04  +2e-04  1e-09  4e-08  1e-04  3e-05  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0
3  -2.993e+04  -2.993e+04  +2e-06  2e-11  5e-10  1e-06  3e-07  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0

OPTIMAL (within feastol=4.7e-10, reltol=5.8e-11, abstol=1.7e-06).
Runtime: 0.000439 seconds.

-29933.999999935182
[ 3.16761905  1.9797619   1.58380952  3.95952381  4.75142857 11.87857143
  5.93928571]
```

It's a different solution than shown in the question. **It's more accurate!**

Even more accurate solutions can be obtained by using linear-programming solvers, which *are not installed by default!*:

```
problem.solve(verbose=True, solver=cp.GLPK)
```

Output:

```
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65
8 rows, 8 columns, 21 non-zeros
*     0: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (1)
*     8: obj =  -2.993400000e+04 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
-29934.000000000004
[ 3.16761905  1.9797619   1.58380952  3.95952381  4.75142857 11.87857143
  5.93928571]
```

Remark: `print()` trimmed/rounded the float-representation.

cvxpy:

- reformulates the problem (especially the non-smooth `min`)
- proves convexity -> solver will provide global-optimum
- setups the (non-python) solver

The approach is more robust due to:

- less general problem-framework -> more aggressive exploitation of math (e.g. no numerical-differentiation)
- usage of simplex or interior-point solvers (very different; but both provide high-accuracy)